# Formula to add 0s after decimal place to reach 8 characters

Tags: excel

As from the title I need a formula to add zeros after the decimal place. This needs to ensure that there are 8 characters for selection.

For example `7305.2` would need to be `7305.002`.

It's required for a **contract reference ID**. Our ERP requires all contract number IDs to be 8 characters long and in the format displayed above.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "extend `7305.2` to `7305.200`"? What you're proposing changes the actual value of the number, not just its representation. Also, will any numbers already be longer than 8 character widths, ie: `1234.56789`?

Comment: Hi, yes I need for it to be 7305.002.

Comment: I donť see any sense in changing number like this. Do you take the value as a number or as something like ID (text)?

Comment: It's required for a contract reference.  Our ERP requires all contract numbers to be 8 digits and in the format I displayed above.

Comment: @Krishn is the first part always 4 digits?

Comment: In the future, please provide as much information as possible. A lot of posters here evidently thought you were trying to changing the logical representation AND the lexical representation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following *User Defined Function* (UDF):

```
Public Function PaddIt(r As Range) As String
    Dim st As String, L As Long
    st = r.Text
    L = Len(st)

    If L >= 8 Then
        PaddIt = st
        Exit Function
    End If

    If InStr(1, st, ".") = 0 Then
        st = st & "."
        If Len(st) = 8 Then
            PaddIt = st
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    While Len(st) < 8
        st = Replace(st, ".", ".0")
    Wend
    PaddIt = st
End Function
```

Here are some sample inputs/outputs:

[image]

If there are already 8 characters, the input is returned.
If there is no "**.**" in the input, then a "**.**" is added.
Zeros are padded after the "**.**" until the length is 8.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=PaddIt(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 2):

Here is formula solution:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",A1)),LEFT(A1&"."&"00000000",8),IF(LEN(A1)<8,LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)&"."&RIGHT("00000000"&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,99),7-LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))),A1))
```

[image]

**EDIT:** [link to Excel fomula beautifier](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/)

Comment: A beautiful alternative to *VBA* ! (+1)

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I wouldn't call this mess as beautiful, but thanks for +1